# How to get a int from another tab?

Tags: android, tabs, wifi

I have got 3 tabs, In tab2 I am scanning for wifi netowrks in a listview. And one of the things I show in tab2 is what channel the wifi is on, there is 14 different channels. Now in tab3 I want to summarize all the channels so I can tell what channel is least used.

This is the loop in tab2 I am using for the scan

```
   for (int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++) {
        ssid = wifiScanList.get(i).SSID; //Get the SSID
        level = wifiScanList.get(i).level;
        channel = wifiScanList.get(i).frequency;

        wifis.add(ssid + " " + level + " dBm "); //append to the other data
        wifis.toString();
    }
```

So what do I include in the loop to get my int channel value everytime it loops to my tab3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use several ways:
1) Make `public static int value;` so you can use it from anywhere.
2) If your tabs are located in the same `Activity` you can create `Intent`, put `extra int value` and call `startActivityForResult` and then do whatever you want in `onActivityResult` with this `int value`.
3) Register some `BroadcastReceiver` and you will get callback where ever you want.